# Why you downgraded your Amarok (or why you didn't upgraded)?

Tags: linux, music, amarok

I disliked **Amarok2** because I think the best part of this software is its editable playlist, where I can fix any tag I want, or order by it, or filter, etc.

And I think its interface is easier than keep creating different areas... I *do* prefer the big editable playlist and its powerful search field.

I can also read many useful information at the *Context Panel*.

So, when I installed a fresh Ubuntu 9.04, the first thing I did was remove Amarok2 and place Amarok1.4 back again, where it should ever stay.

### And you? Why you disliked Amarok2?

Comment: Community wiki please: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amarok 1.4 handled various artist albums really, really well. Every time I try giving Amarok 2 a spin, it fails miserably on this.  This is the main reason.

Also, it doesn't seem to recognise album art files in the same folder, only those embedded in the actual music file.

Basically they got really distracted by lots of shiny things and lost the core features that made it so good in the first place.

Comment: Just an update, have come across a nice player called Clementine http://www.clementine-player.org/ which is heavily inspired by Amarok 1.4, covers my two gripes above, and runs on Linux, MacOS & windows. noice.

Answer (score 1):

Basically because I'm not a fan of the new design in 2.0. For me personally It's just not as clean as 1.4. I've even started moving away from 1.4 now and onto [banshee](http://banshee-project.org/).

Answer (score 1):

because you cant crossfade between songs any more. I have a DJ system rockin ubuntu and amrok, but no update since we cant crossfade

Comment: really you can't crossfade?? OMG!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using Amarok 1.4 is that it's no longer developed, so will slowly fall by the wayside as bugs and incompatibilities are found. I've found Banshee to be a decent replacement as well.

Answer (score 0):

Visualization support is gone! Along with a bunch of the other features I use ... custom colors, not crashing all the time, and more. Haven't tried Banshee, though.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten my Dell Jukebox (circa 2003) to work with Amarok2 yet, so "lack of mp3 player support" is my reason for staying with Amarok 1.4...